# Resend Stripe receipt by email

Tags: c#, stripe-payments

Using the C# Stripe API is there a way to re-send a receipt to an email address for a successful payment? I could not see any API methods to do this one.

Answer (score 0):

Not limited to C# but there is no API to resend a receipt. You can manually [send it via Dashboard](https://stripe.com/docs/receipts?payment-ui=elements#manually-send-receipts-from-the-dashboard), or programmatically retrieve the [receipt URL](https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/object#charge_object-receipt_url) and write a logic to send it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by updating the `receipt_email` attribute of the Charge object:
https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/update?lang=dotnet#update_charge-receipt_email

> If this field is updated, then a new email receipt will be sent to the updated address.